# Image Objects into table javascript

Tags: javascript, image, object, preload

Hey I'm struggling with a task I have been given for my course.

I have been asked to preload 20 images into the browser cache and then place the images into a table. this has to be done with Javascript.

I don't know were I'm going wrong as I'm relying on google for most of my answers.

here is what I have so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
function preloadimages() 

{

     // counter
     var i = 0;
  
  // Table Construct
  var table = '';
  var rows = 4;
  var cols = 5;

     // set image list
     var preload =  [["../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c1.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c2.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c4.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r1_c5.jpg"],
      ["../../images/Large/bcpot002_r2_c1.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r2_c2.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r2_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r2_c4.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r2_c5.jpg"],
      ["../../images/Large/bcpot002_r3_c1.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r3_c2.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r3_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r3_c4.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r3_c5.jpg"],
      ["../../images/Large/bcpot002_r4_c1.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r4_c2.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r4_c3.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r4_c4.jpg","../../images/Large/bcpot002_r4_c5.jpg"]];

     var images = [];
for (i = 0; i < preload.length; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = preload[i];
  // make the table.
   for(var r = 0; r < rows;r++)
   {
    table += '<tr class="myTr">';
    for(var c = 0; c < cols;c++)
     {
      table += '<td id="myTd">' + images + '</td>';
     }
  table += '</tr>';
 }
//Place table.
document.getElementById('ImageContent').innerHTML = '<table class="myTable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" align="center">' + table + '</table>';
}

   
 

}
```

Comment: It's obviously not going to work because you can't just take DOM objects, concatenate them into a string and expect them to show up in your HTML page, that's not how the DOM works. Either you use only strings, or you use only DOM Element and the DOM api, but you can't do both. If you don't know what the DOM is, I suggest you to either learn how the DOM works OR just use strings. Like `"<img src='"+sourceVariable+"'/>"` for each image, then use innerHTML to display the result. It's not going to preload anything though, you need to learn to use event listeners and listen to the `load` event.

Comment: ok So you would suggest I preload the images. Build a table with javascript and then onload insert ithe img objects into the cells?